# Is this a correct implementation of Q-Learning for Checkers?

Tags: machine-learning, pseudocode, agent, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am trying to understand **Q-Learning**,

---

My current algorithm operates as follows:

**1.** A lookup table is maintained that maps a state to information about its immediate reward and utility for each action available.

**2.** At each state, check to see if it is contained in the lookup table and initialise it if not (With a default utility of 0).

**3.** Choose an action to take with a probability of:

```
    (*ϵ* = 0>ϵ>1 - probability of taking a random action)
    1-ϵ = Choosing the state-action pair with the highest utility.
    ϵ = Choosing a random move.
    ϵ decreases over time.
```

**4.** Update the current state's utility based on:

```
    Q(st, at) += a[rt+1, + d.max(Q(st+1, a)) - Q(st,at)]
```

---

I am currently playing my agent against a simple **heuristic player**, who always takes the move that will give it the best *immediate reward*.

**The results** - The results are very poor,  even after a couple hundred games, the Q-Learning agent is losing **a lot more** than it is winning. Furthermore, the change in win-rate is almost non-existent, especially after reaching a couple hundred games.

Am I missing something? I have implemented a couple agents:

*(Rote-Learning, TD(0), TD(Lambda), Q-Learning)*

But they all seem to be yielding similar, *disappointing*, results.

[image]

Comment: Running a simulation as I type this, ill update the main post with an image of some results momentarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are on the order of 10²⁰ different states in checkers, and you need to play a whole game for every update, so it will be a very, very long time until you get meaningful action values this way. Generally, you'd want a simplified state representation, like a neural network, to solve this kind of problem using reinforcement learning.

Also, a couple of caveats:

- Ideally, you should update 1 value per game, because the moves in a single game are highly correlated.
- You should initialize action values to small random values to avoid large policy changes from small Q updates.

Comment: Thanks! And just to clarify, are you saying that TD(0) is unlikely to show any improvement for Checkers  over say 1000 games,

Comment: @Samalot, I would not be surprised if it did not improve after a million.